# How to use Blob Storage as shared storage in a Windows Azure Failover Cluster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, storage, azure-vm

In the context of SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition, is it possible to make Azure Blob storage available to a SQL Failover cluster directly as a shared SCSI resource on a Windows Cluster composed on VM's on Azure? An Azure blob is effectively shared storage, and a newly added disk on an Azure VM, does show up as a SCSI disk, before it is converted into a Volume (GPT).

But converting it into a GPT volume on one of the nodes, or on another node defeats the purpose (making that node a single point of failure). The ideal solution should involve directly exposing it to the Windows Cluster (before setting up the SQL Server Cluster).

Does SQL Server support writing to such a shared blob storage, directly, from two clustered instances?

Comment: as per this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/05bbfa0f-4ece-4380-aba6-8a052f7048ba/is-it-possible-to-have-a-cluster-disk-from-cloud-storage?forum=windowsazuredata), looks like it is not possible to directly cluster the Azure disks ...

Comment: and this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/f3e38072-53f7-4589-8218-0e921016df7a/is-it-possible-to-have-a-cluster-disk-from-cloud-storage?forum=windowsazuredata)